# Run command inside INFLUXDB container using docker-compose not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I've managed to set an initial docker-compose.yml file with env variables defining the initial bucket, org, token, ...
After the container is running, if I access the shell and do

```
influx bucket create -n teste -o my-org
```

the bucket is created successfully

but if I do the following in docker-compose (only added the "command" instruction)

```
version: "3"
services:
  influxdb:
    container_name: influxdb
    image: influxdb
    volumes:
      - influxdb-storage:/var/lib/influxdb2:rw
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always
    command: /bin/sh -c "influx bucket create -n teste -o my-org"
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT}:8086
```

I get the error: Error: failed to lookup org with name "my-org":
How can I create the 2nd bucket using the docker-compose?
thank you